# vertical align on display-block div

Tags: html, css

I need to center the text vertically in the block, there may be many. The size of each block fixed 111px/63px.

```
.producers {
  width: 100%;  
}

.producer {
    width: 111px;
    height: 63px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
.producer img {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

The code can be seen by reference

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7H4JS/1/)

Comment: Yes and blocks may be present in the picture

Answer (score 0):

change add line-**height** property to the **producers** class
with height equal to your producer class height property

```
.producers{
   width : 100%;
   line-height:63px;
}
```